# получение свойства обьекта из обьекта который находится в массиве

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, как правильно организовать код, чтобы достать свойство объекта из объекта который находится в массиве в конструкции (if) возле пометки(ПОМЕТКА!!)  вроде всё просто но не фурычит =) в той конструкции мне необходимо дальше провести сравнение есть ли в таком объекте цвет зелёный и если да то делаю какие либо дальше действия, к примеру выглядеть должно так - if(myBasketKey[i][hash].color == 'green') , но если  я пишу if(myBasketKey[i][hash].color =='green') - будет ошибка : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'color' of undefined. Ниже привожу пример до которого уровня всё же удалось мне добраться

```js
var myBasketKey = [

  {
    "hash1": {
      "color": "BLUE",
      "size": "1",
      "count": 1
    }
  }, {
    "hash2": {
      "color": "RED",
      "size": "22",
      "count": 22
    }
  }, {
    "hash3": {
      "color": "GREEN",
      "size": "33",
      "count": 33
    }
  }, {
    "hash4": {
      "color": "RED",
      "size": "22",
      "count": 22
    }
  }
]

var hash = "hash2";

switch (hash) {
  case 'hash1':
  case 'hash2':
  case 'hash3':
    for (var i = 0; i < myBasketKey.length; i++) {
      if (myBasketKey[i][hash]) { //ПОМЕТКА!!!!!!!!!
        console.log('есть такой: ', myBasketKey[i][hash]);
        break;
      }
    }
    break;
  default:
    for (var i = 0; i < myBasketKey.length; i++) {
      if (!myBasketKey[i].hasOwnProperty(hash)) {
        console.log('любое действие когда нету');
        break;
      }
    }
    break;

}
```

Comment: а в чем проблема с кодом в вопросе?

Comment: @Grundy - "но не фурычит"

Comment: @Igor, так оно вроде фурычит, или не вполне понятно что автор хочет

Comment: @Утка - "It's an industry term." - "My cousin Vinny"

Comment: возле пометки (ПОМЕТКА!) я дошёл до обьекта, но мне нужно изьять его свойство, если я пишу    if(myBasketKey[i][hash].color =='green') - будет ошибка : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'color' of undefined

Comment: данный кусок работает, я привёл рабочий кусок просто. Но мне не это нужно, я выше чуть постом пояснил что нужно до свойства обьекта дойти и произвести сравнение, но я не могу выбрать это свойство, куда там дальше сравниват ьего с чем то)

Comment: А. Понял. Ну тогда так: if (myBasketKey[i][hash] && myBasketKey[i][hash].color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему ошибка?
Потому что у вас массив объектов, содержащих объекты. Соответственно `myBasket[0]["hash2"] - undefined.` Ну то есть нет в вашем первом объекте свойства с ключом "hash2", "hash1" только есть.

Попытка обратиться к свойству переменной со значением `undefined` (что-то типа `undefined.myProperty`) вызывает в js ошибку вроде:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'myProperty' of undefined

Решается это стандартным трюком:

```
if (myBasketKey[i][hash] && myBasketKey[i][hash].color === "GREEN"){
 //dosmth
}
```

Смысл в том, что в js, как и в большинстве других языков, правая часть этого логического выражения не выполняется, если по левой заведомо понятно, что оно ложно.

Тут немножко усложняет понимание то, что у вас вообще какая-то переусложненная структура. В примере достаточно массива плоских объектов, а не массива объектов содержащих объекты.

Comment: спасибо огромное ! помог очень! а можно узнать почему он ругался ?

Comment: @user3319778, обновил ответ.

Comment: всё чётко и понятно, спасибо огромнейшее !!! Кстати а структура такая потому что я эти обьекты сохраняю в локал сторадж, но была проблема что при добавлении обьектов в локал сторадж в рандомном порядке  он автоматически сортировал их и выставлял последовательно у себя,когда мне нужно было что б они оставались в порядке добавления туда(хаотичном порядке), вот я решил  закинуть их в массив, у меня хэш-всегда уникальное  значение  вот и решил обернуть обьект в ещё один обьект поэтому

Comment: в целом Ваш ответ помог - спасибо, но есть баг, если в свйостве обьекта нету цвета "green" , то блок default не отработает

Comment: @user3319778, ненене, это не мой баг) Блок default - он отрабатывает в зависимости от значения выражения в switch(); Ну то есть я не пытался все-все у вас пофиксить, а толкьо описанную проблему